# How to override warning in Taskwarrior?

Tags: command-line, configuration, utilities, taskwarrior

I have the following output whenever I issue `task`:

```
TASKRC override: /path/taskrc
TASKDATA override: /path/.task
```

It's because I put the config and data files in non-default external location specified by `$TASKRC` and `$TASKDATA` environment variables of [Taskwarrior](https://taskwarrior.org/).

How could I make `task` to be quiete and not warn me everytime.

I'd like to find the command line switch to make it quiet for the issueing time (once) and the also config file option to make it permanent, if any.

Comment: Would it be possible, instead of overriding configuration, to create soft links, in place of the expected files, linking to your own?

Comment: No, I don't want to create symlinks. If the variables are available, then the use of them should be done too I think.

Comment: Note that this was reported upstream in https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/issues/442#issuecomment-365138121 with recommended resolution similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406599/108198

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to lower the [verbosity](https://taskwarrior.org/docs/verbosity.html) by removing `header` from `verbose`. By default, `verbose=yes`, so you need to manually list each type of message that you want to see.

For example, I fixed this by fully defining verbosity minus a few items:

```
verbose=blank,footnote,label,new-id,affected,edit,special,project,sync,unwait
```

in my `~/.config/task/config` (or whatever your `$TASKRC` is). Note that I also removed `filter` from my verbosity, but that's not necessary to fix the problem. Just remove `header`.

Note also that removing `header` will also hide the `[task custom]` message at the top of the output. If you need that message, the alternative would be to manually filter out the warning using `grep` and some regular expressions.

**TL;DR:** place this in the file at `$TASKRC`:

```
verbose=blank,footnote,label,new-id,affected,edit,special,project,sync,unwait
```

Comment: (to document:) this was done by issuing `task show verbose` to get the value and `task config verbose=(list)` where `header` field was removed from the list retrieved.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this solution turns out to hide important output, and it could be difficult to hide the warning using `grep`. If that's the case though, I'd call this error a bug in Taskwarrior.

Comment: What is [task custom] used for?

Comment: @StevieD [task custom] is prefixed to custom Taskwarrior reports